# Can I change Angular-Fullstack's automatic naming conventions?

Tags: node.js, yeoman-generator, yo

When I use generator-angular-fullstack's API to build routes, controllers, directives, whathaveyou, it appends naming conventions I don't like. For instance for all the module declarations it appends "App", and I'd prefer to not have "App" appended to my app name. Also, it uses "Ctrl" instead of "Controller", and so on.

I'm not seeing a json file that controls this behavior in my app or my angular-fullstack npm files. There's a good chance I'm overlooking something or not even looking in the right place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot edit the templates directly. You can either go back and rename them, or generate your own templates by replacing the routing through your `.yo-rc.json` file. It's located in the root folder of the project in all angular-fullstack apps unless removed.

It looks like angular-fullstack uses the generator-ng-component node module for the templates, here's a link to the github repo for controller template specifically. You could also make your own, fork it, then use it as your own generator.

https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-ng-component/blob/master/templates/controller/name.controller.js